# Contributing to an opensource C++ library

Tags: c++, boost

How should i get it, by SVN?
Can i use Eclipse and its Subversive Team Provider add on to manage my changes? 
Then if i make some changes how can i commit, who decide that my changes are friendly and good enough?
To be honest i want to try to contribute to some library, because of motivation that contribution provides me on learning C++ details.

I search and read a little about Boost, but i think it is too complicated to be a starting point.

Thus can you provide a path to start and become an open source library contributor?

Answer (score 7):

Well, the very first step is to actually read the FAQ. That's always a good start.

Especially the "How can I contribute to development?" question.

http://www.boost.org/users/faq.html